# Create a row on a table using a link - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new at Ruby so my question may be really simple.

I have a table with rows (the users for example) and columns with information such as Name Adress PhoneNumber, and I'd like to put a link in the end of each row to create automatically (if I click on the link) a row in another table in my database, using the information of the user (on the row).

How should I do that ? How to create a button or a link, and where to write the code to add a row in a different table using those information ?

I'm sorry if my question isn't clear. Thank you !

Comment: Question is too vague. You need to combine view, application and database. Please follow a tutorial to do that. For example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: You can do it, but the answer would be too detailed for stack overflow. Basically, you would need what's called a member route in your routes.db (`resources :users do; member do; get 'other';  end; end`) and that will give you a path you can link to called `other_user_path(user)` and you would have an action in your controller called `other` that can retrieve the user information and create your new table entry.   In short, yes it's possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in case someone needs it:
We have to touch the routes, the controller and the view.

About the routes: we just have to add a root to a method we'll create in the controller.

About the controller: create this method and put it in something like "other = Other.new( and the parameters here)" and then the save part which is just like the function create !

About the view: put a button_to function, specifying the path and the data we want to send to the controller.

Cheers